# HTML e JAVASCRIPT table scan

Tags: javascript, html, performance, html-table

I've a very big table in a HTML page and I create a text input for show only the matching row of the table. 
This is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">
<table id="tabella">
<tr><th>TIPO</th><th>SCHEMA</th><th>NOME</th><th>DDL</th></tr>
<tr><td>[...]</td></tr>
[...] > 10000 rows
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;

    var table = document.getElementById('tabella');

    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) 
    {   
        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) 
        {
            $(row).hide();
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) 
    {

        if ( row.cells[2].innerHTML.includes(x)  )
        {
            $(row).show();
        }   
    }   
}
</script>
```

The problem is:
When I type a single character in the input field it waits for a very long time Is there a mode for rewrite that is  faster?

Comment: could you explain how you want to filter? filter by id? name ect?

Comment: Why are you looking over all the cells and hiding the same row, over and over?

Comment: I fiter the table by the contents of the 3^ column: if ( row.cells[2].innerHTML.includes(x)  ). The rows haven't an ID

Comment: Because if someone delete the input i want that all rows are examintated.

Comment: You should not be looping over all the cells to hide them. That is a waste. It should just be looping over the rows and hiding it. (and really you do not need to do that....) Just loop over the table, read the row html and see if it includes your string.If yes, show it, if no, hide it.

Comment: @epascarello It's simpler and faster to just hide all the rows and then only show matching ones. While looping does happen under the covers,  using JQuery's `:find()` with `:contains` eliminates the need to write any loops.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes and no.... Yes it is simpler, but you are looking over it two times, hiding and showing...

Comment: @epascarello See my comment edit.

Comment: There are loops under the hood. ;)

Comment: @epascarello That's what I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you can do to improve the performance...

- Don't use `.innerHTML` when the text you are working with doesn't
  contain HTML because the browser engages the HTML parser every time
  you use this. For getting/setting text that does not contain HTML,
  use `.textContent`. In JQuery, the analogous methods are `.html()` and `.text()`.
- Don't scan the DOM for elements that you've already scanned for
  previously. This means make cached variable references to your DOM
  objects outside of your repeatedly called functions.
- Rather than looping over every row  and cell manually, and since you are using
  JQuery, just get all the rows into a JQuery wrapped set and work with
  that collection. Use the **[JQuery
  `.find()` method](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** with the **[JQuery `:contains` selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #demo { margin-top:1em; padding:3px; width:20%; font-weight:bold;
            border:1px solid #aa0; background:#ee3; height:1em; 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="myInput">
<table id="tabella">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>TIPO</th>
    <th>SCHEMA</th>
    <th>NOME</th>
    <th>DDL</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
  <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
  <td>row 1, cell 21</td>
  <td>row 1, cell 3</td>
  <td>row 1, cell 4</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
  <td>row 2, cell 21</td>
  <td>row 2, cell 3</td>
  <td>row 2, cell 4</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>row 3, cell 1</td>
  <td>row 3, cell 21</td>
  <td>row 3, cell 3</td>
  <td>row 3, cell 4</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>row 4, cell 1</td>
  <td>row 4, cell 21</td>
  <td>row 4, cell 3</td>
  <td>row 4, cell 4</td> 
</tr>
</table>

<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
  // Get your DOM references outside of the callback function
  // so that you aren't scanning the DOM over and over for the
  // same elements.
  let $tbl = $("#tabella");
  let $dem = $("#demo");

  // Don't use inline HTML event handlers (i.e. oninput). 
  // Do all of yor JavaScript outside of the HTML
  $("#myInput").on("input", myFunction);

  function myFunction() {
    // Hide all the rows in the table, except the header row
    // (<tbody> is implicitly created)
    $("tbody > tr",$tbl).hide();
   
    // Then, find the row(s) that contain the entered text and show only them.
    let $found = $tbl.find("tbody > tr:contains('" + this.value + "')").show();
    
    // Don't use .innerHTML for non-HTML strings, use .textContent instead.
    // In JQuery, that's .text() instead of .html()
    $dem.text($found.length + " records found.");    
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok perfect, thanks! Now the search is more fast but there is a problema for the first page load. Is there a mode for not load all the table at the begin but only after an user type some word?

Comment: @MicheleM Yes, it's the same `input` event that the current function is a callback for. You'd need to add the code that loads the table at the beginning of that current function and then have a Boolean variable (that is declared outside of the function) that is set to `true`. Then, all the code that loads the table would go inside of an `if` condition that only runs if the Boolean variable is `false`. That way, you only load the table the first time someone begins typing in the field. But, I have to say that this may not be desirable because there could be a delay after typing that 1st char.

Answer (score -1):

Thank guys I found the solution:

```
<script>
var $rows = $('#tabella tr');
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is not the solution. No need for any string manipulations, which themselves are expensive. See my answer.